# Custom input using VueFormulate and V-Calendar

Tags: vue-formulate

I'm creating a vueformulate custom input for v-calendar, but I can't seem to get validation working correctly. The required validation errors initially even though a value is set and doesn't change upon subsequent input changes.

How can I get the validation to reflect when the model is valid?

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-haibt-mtt16?file=/src/App.vue

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you find solution ? I am also stuck at this point

Comment: @Radeanu No I haven't. I'm having to manually do validation checks outside of vueFormulate for now.